# How do I reference Text under TextRange?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So I'm trying to debug this script I have, one error I can't get past:

```
Dim pptText As String
pptText = Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
```

I'm getting an error saying Object needed, and when I do this:

```
Dim pptText
pptText = Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
```

it will run without errors, but pptText is then not set to the text I want. I'm trying to reference this part of the shape (Highlighted in blue) I want it to return "hee": https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGFVY.jpg

I've tried

```
Dim pptText
pptText = Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

but that's probably a laughable attempt, and does not work. I have no idea what I can do at this point. Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not shown your entire VBA code, but I suspect that your reference to `Shape` in your code is causing the error. '*Shape*' can't be the name of your variable referencing the `Shape` object type because it's a reserved word in VBA.

I set up a slide that has a single text frame containing "hee" and was able to execute the following code with no errors and the expected result.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim tf As TextFrame
    Dim pptText As String

    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        Debug.Print sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: I had 
    shpe As Shape
but I noticed you also didnt Set pptText = to anything. And that made me realize I didn't need to set anything either and it worked!

Could you explain to me btw what the difference between 'Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides _
                                                            (PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex) 

and Set pptSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide are?

Comment: Here is my entire code: https://pastebin.com/xh0uRPGd I am still not very certain when to use Set and when not to. my "iq_Array" variable has no Type right now because it is giving me the same problem as "pptText" was

Comment: You use SET when assigning an object to a variable (e.g. SETting a variable dimmed as Shape to a particular shape) and = when assigning a value to a variable (e.g. your pptText, defined as a string variable).  Incidentally, your pptText = Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text would have worked if you'd first SET Shape = [some shape on the slide], though as PeterT mentioned, it's not a good idea to use reserved words (Shape, for example) as variable names.

Comment: Thank you, perfect explanation! Also, thanks for all the content you put out on your website, it is how I was able to write any code at all!